# MarkLogic: how to return a html page from ML server with a 404 header?

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, uri, xquery, marklogic

I'm developing a REST application, which uses a uri rewriter, which points to an options element that defines the route. Everything works apart from the 404 response: the right page is returned but with a 200 header, not 404.

If I return a string instead of the html page, the 404 header is sent. How can I return a html page with a 404 response?

This is what I currently have:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace rest = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/rest"
 at "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/rest.xqy"; 

import module namespace requests =   "http://myrequests"
 at "requests.xqy";

declare option xdmp:mapping "false";

declare variable $result := rest:rewrite($requests:options) ;
  if (empty($result))
    then (xdmp:set-response-code(404, "Not found"), '/FAIL.html' )
   else
      $result
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with returning a string instead?

Comment: I meant, instead of returning a html page, just return a string: `  if (empty($result))
    then (xdmp:set-response-code(404, "Not found"), 
 "that resource wasn't found"
    )`

Comment: Ha, in that case MarkLogic will look within the modules database for a resource called "that resource wasn't found", then wouldn't be able to find it, and return a 404 by its default behavior. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to not do the xdmp:set-response-code within the rewriter itself. You could change the fail.html into a fail.xqy that contains both the html (as well-formed xml), and the xdmp:set-response-code. You could potentially use it for multiple purposes, and pass in code and message as request params from the rewriter, by simply adding them to the redirect url..

It should also be possible to leverage the error-handler, and throw a specific error message from within the rewrite, capture that in the error-handler.xqy, and make that return a specific error page. Slightly more awkward to pass-through extra info though, but that should be possible..

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

The error-handler.xqy approach gives you a lot of flexibility and some good encapsulation of error response handling for your rest service.  For services I've developed, we create a table that maps specific 500 error codes coming from the server to the appropriate http status codes and messages, and formats the response bodies consistently.  As you run into error that you want handled as something other than 500, then it's just a matter of adding to the mapping table.